# Passing data from db_helper Activity to Fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

for Sending Data:

```
val u = Users()
val b = Bundle()
b.putStringArrayList("name01", name01)
u.arguments=b
```

for Receiving Data:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, 
                          container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
  strtext = arguments!!.getStringArrayList("name01")
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false)
}
```

output: `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`

How should I get the data?
Is there is another Method?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce my friend there is no such kind of Syntax in Kotlin.

Comment: ...bah they have `requireActivity()` but they don't have `requireArguments()` by default, how weird

Comment: Trying to sort this out myself right now. I'm an iOS guy...data is a no brainer there. Can't believe how clunky data handling is in Android. Anyway, you're getting an exception because you're force unwrapping the arguments optional. Always do this instead: arguments?.getStringArrayList("name01")